# Countably-infinite discontinuous unitary irreps

Tags: representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, lie-groups

Consider a compact Lie group (for simplicity let it be $SO(3)$). All unitary irreps of the corresponding Lie algebra are finite-dimensional.

However, the same is not true for the group. As a counter example, consider a vector space spanned by points on the 2-sphere (taken as linearly independent basis elements). $SO(3)$ obviously acts on that vector space, but there is no well defined $\mathfrak{so}_3$ action, because the representation is discontinuous. It is straightforward to show that the representation is unitary and irreducible.

However, the vector space in this counter example is nonseparable.

Are there any infinite-dimensional (discontinuous or non-differentiable) unitary irreps of $SO(3)$ acting on the separable Hilbert space? If not, which theorem forbids their existence?

Comment: Is $SO(2)$ a typo?

Comment: @CharlieFrohman indeed, thank you.

Comment: @CharlieFrohman although a version of this question for $SO(2)$ is also interesting to me, as all unitary irreps of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{u}_1$ are 1-dimensional, but a similar discontinuous counter example exists (vector space spanned by linearly independent points on the circle).

Comment: If a unitary a representation exist on a separable Hilbert space, it is by a very different construction than the one in your example. Nontrivial $SO(3)$ homogeneous spaces are uncountable.

Comment: @CharlieFrohman sure, I’m not denying that. That’s why I asked the question :)

Comment: $SO(3)$ lies in $PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$. There should be some separable Hilbert space that is a unitary rep of that group derived from hyperbolic geometry, by taking forms with growth conditions on a cusp of a hyperbolic three manifold of finite volume. Maybe restrict such a representation?

Comment: @CharlieFrohman unless I misunderstood you, that representation is continuous and differentiable, making it an algebra representation. Any restriction to $SO(3)$ will thus also induce a rep of $\mathfrak{so}_3$, which means that there is no infinite-dimensional irreps.

Comment: Good point. It’s a good question.